# How to do an Epsilon/N Argument for this sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Having some trouble doing a formal argument for proving the limit of the following sequence,

$$a_n=\frac{n}{4^n}$$

The limit is zero, but how do I go about doing an epsilon/N argument for proving the limit? First steps or solutions welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $n<2^n$ and $4^n=(2^n)^2$, so the quotient $a_n$ satisfies $\displaystyle 0<a_n<\frac1{2^n}<\frac1n$. Now, given $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N$ with $1/N<\epsilon$, so any $n>N$ also satisfies $1/n<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

First prove that $n<2^n$ by induction.

Then you can write $a_n=\frac n{4^n}<\frac{2^n}{4^n}=\frac1{2^n}$.

Surely for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that $\frac1N<\varepsilon$, then for any $n\leq N$ we have $-\varepsilon<a_n<\frac1{2^n}<\frac1n\leq\frac1N<\varepsilon\Longrightarrow|a_n-0|<\varepsilon$, so by definition $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.